# Easy way to find failed files using wget -i

Tags: unix, wget

I have a list of files (images, pdfs) and I want download them all via wget (using option -i). The problem is that I got different number of files downloaded - some are missing. All files in list are unique - I already double-check.

I know, that I can compare my list with 'ls' in folder, but I'm curious if there is some "wget" way to find failed operations.

UPDATE:
My problem in steps:

- I have list 'list.txt' with URLs
- I run command:

  ```
  wget -i list.txt
  ```
- for each file I get a long output with status e.g:

  ```
  --2015-07-07 13:46:34--  http://www.example.com/example.png
  Reusing existing connection to www.example.com:80.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
  Length: 261503 (255K) [image/png]
  Saving to: 'example.png'

  example.png    100%[===================================================>] 255.37K  1.51MB/s   in 0.2s   

  2015-07-07 13:46:34 (1.51 MB/s) - 'example.png' saved [261503/261503]
  ```
- at the end i got 1 more message:

  ```
  FINISHED --2015-07-07 13:46:34--
  Total wall clock time: 1m 15s
  Downloaded: 109 files, 130M in 1m 11s (1.84 MB/s)
  ```

My question is: I have 'list.txt' with 112 lines, the result told me that it downloads 109 files, so how can I know which files are not downloaded?

Comment: wget will certainly return a failure code if it fails  to successfully complete its task. It sounds like you forgot to check for this in your script, but since you haven't provided any code,  we can't know for sure.

Comment: I updated my question and describe it more in detail with real example, is it more clear now?